# Erlang swap two element in list

Tags: list, erlang, swap

How can I quickly swap two elements in Erlang list?

For example I have list: `[1,2,3,4]`, how can I quickly get `[1,3,2,4]`?

Comment: Do you mean switch or replace?

Comment: You want to swap the elements do you? If you edit your question and add the info how you want to specify what elements you want to swap, I'll add these to my answer.

Comment: In your example you swap element 2 with element 3.  If you want to replace 2 elements instead, could you please tell us which 2 elements you want to replace by what exactly?

Comment: Maybe you just need to use tuples instead of lists?

Answer (score 4):

You did not say in your question how you want to specify which two element you want to swap.

If you just want to swap the elements at position 2 and 3 in a list (like in your example):

```
swap23([A,B,C|Rest]) ->
     [A,C,B|Rest].
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you wish to swap any index with another you can do the following

```
swap(List,S1,S2) -> {List2,[F|List3]} = lists:split(S1-1,List),
   LT = List2++[lists:nth(S2,List)|List3],
   {List4,[_|List5]} = lists:split(S2-1,LT),
   List4++[F|List5].
```

Comment: Yeah if he wants to swap ... I tried to edit the question to make it understandable, but @shk insists he wants to replace and not swap (see comments of Q) but doesn't tell us what he wants to replace with what.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you only traverse the list once.

```
swap(A, B, List) ->
    {P1, P2} = {min(A,B), max(A,B)},
    {L1, [Elem1 | T1]} = lists:split(P1-1, List),
    {L2, [Elem2 | L3]} = lists:split(P2-P1-1, T1), 
    lists:append([L1, [Elem2], L2, [Elem1], L3]).
```

Usage example:

```
1> swap(6,2,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).
[1,6,3,4,5,2,7,8]
```